# MySql Search Query for Two Combined Fields

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am working on a site that allows users to list boats and yachts for sale. There is a mysql database that has a table "yachts" and among other fields ther are "make" and "model".

When people come to the site to look for boats for sale there is a search form, one of the options is to enter the make and/or model into a text field. The relevant where clause on the results page is the following

```
WHERE ( make LIKE '%$yacht_make%' OR model  LIKE '%$yacht_make%')
```

This is working if someone enters *either* the make  *or* model but not if they enter both.

For example, if someone enters "Jeanneau", the make, it finds the boat with that make, or if they enter "Sun Odyssey", the model, it finds the boat of that model, but if they enter "Jeanneau Sun Odyssey" it comes up empty.

Is there is a way to write a query where all three ways of entering the above search criteria would find the boat?

Here is the site http://yachtsoffered.com/

Thanks,

Rob Fenwick

Edit:

The query is built with a php script here is the script

```
    if(!empty($yacht_id)) {
    $where = " WHERE yacht_id = $yacht_id ";
} else {
    $where = " WHERE ( make LIKE '%$yacht_make%' OR model  LIKE '%$yacht_make%') ";
    if(!empty($year_from) && !empty($year_to)){
        $where .= "AND ( year BETWEEN $year_from AND $year_to ) ";
    }
    if(!empty($length_from) && !empty($length_to)){
        $where .= "AND ( length_ft BETWEEN $length_from AND $length_to ) ";
    }
    if(!empty($price_from) && !empty($price_to)){
        $where .= "AND ( price BETWEEN $price_from AND $price_to ) ";
    }
    if ($sail_power != 2){
        $where .= "AND ( sail_power = $sail_power ) ";
    }
    if (count($material_arr) > 0){
        $material = 'AND  (';
        foreach ($material_arr as $value) {
            $material .= ' material LIKE \'%' . $value . '%\' OR';
        }
        $material = substr_replace ( $material , ') ' , -2 );
        $where .= $material;
    }
    if (count($engine_arr) > 0){
        $engine = 'AND  (';
        foreach ($engine_arr as $value) {
            $engine .= ' engine LIKE \'%' . $value . '%\' OR';
        }
        $engine = substr_replace ( $engine , ') ' , -2 );
        $where .= $engine;
    }
    if (count($type_arr) > 0){
        $type = 'AND  (';
        foreach ($type_arr as $value) {
            $type .= ' type LIKE \'' . $value . '\' OR';
        }
        $type = substr_replace ( $type , ') ' , -2 );
        $where .= $type;
    }
    if (count($region_arr) > 0){
        $region = 'AND  (';
        foreach ($region_arr as $value) {
            $region .= ' region LIKE \'' . $value . '\' OR';
        }
        $region = substr_replace ( $region , ') ' , -2 );
        $where .= $region;
    }       
        $where .= 'AND ( active = 1 ) ORDER BY yacht_id DESC';
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name $where LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Can you post your whole query?

Comment: when both are entered your search the one field with both make and model, so it fails, you need to either explicitly separate the 2, use 2 inputs, or split the text the user inputs

Comment: Thanks Dagon, yes I understand why it's not working, I thought of serparating the two input fields but I wanted to know if there is another option first, the problem with spiting them is there is no way to tell which words are the make which the model, I suppose I could search for each word separately but that would bring up too many results.

Comment: Make: XXX (input field). Model: XXXX (input field), that's how i would do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, the easiest one in my opinion is:

```
$search = preg_replace('/\s+/','|', $yacht_make);
$sql = "select * from yacht where concat_ws(' ',make,model) rlike '$search'";
```

This replaces all whitespace with `|`, that is used as `OR` in regexp-powered-like query on concatenation of all searchable fields. The speed of it may be questionable in heavy trafic sites but is quite compact and easy to add more fields.

Comment: So easy to do. RLIKE is far underused in answers to mysql questions. Also like the concat_ws. References for folks are CONCAT_WS (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) and RLIKE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Comment: I am getting this error for the preg_replace line Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\yachtsoffered\results.php on line 70

Comment: @tadman I like to believe in people, so since there is no `like '%{$_POST['yacht_make']}%'` in the query, I'm assuming `$yacht_make` is already escaped :)

Comment: Assumptions are what lead to gigantic failures. If it's not obvious it's escaped, it needs to be escaped. Sorry, but being casual about these things gets people into serious trouble.

Comment: It's also not obvious that OP is using some other credentials than root with no password from default mysql installation. That's why I prefer `obviously wrong` policy to mention such things.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in your query you are searching for the exact substring "Jeanneau Sun Odyssey", which is neither a make nor a model.

The easiest solution is to use to separate input boxes for make and model. But if you really need to use a single input box, your best bet would be to split on spaces and add clauses for each separate word, so your query will end up looking something like

```
WHERE make like '%sun%' OR model like '%sun%' 
OR make like '%odyssey%' OR model like '%odyssey%' 
OR make like '%Jeanneau%' OR model like '%Jeanneau%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
WHERE make LIKE '%$yacht_make%'
   OR model  LIKE '%$yacht_make%'
   OR '$yacht_make' LIKE CONCAT('%', make, '%', model, '%')
   OR '$yacht_make' LIKE CONCAT('%', model, '%', make, '%')
```

It will not be very efficient and still not catch all possibilities, e.g. if the user provide the make and a part of the model name, like `'Jeanneau Odyssey'` or in wrong order: `Sun Jeanneau Odyssey`.

Comment: the number of times i have been in this position and not know you could do this! I'm going to go change some searches now so i have it in my code - thanks

Comment: @Dagon queries with `LIKE '%searchstring'` are not efficient though.

Comment: Reversed arguments in LIKE is nice feature, but here it would make anything hard to find - you would have to provide exact make and model, optionally separated, prefixed and followed by anything unrelated, but no results for queries with only make or only model or with part of each one. It would find `"123 Jeanneau 123 Sea Odyssey 213"`, but no `"Jeanneau Odyssey"`

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I don't think I follow your objection.

Comment: @ypercube Fiddle to illustrate typical searches: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e979c/4 all returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone I ended up using dev-null-dweller's solution above

I revised my code as following,

to get the value and escape here is the code,

```
    if (isset($_GET['yacht_make'])) {
    $yacht_make  = cleanString($_GET['yacht_make']);
    $yacht_make = preg_replace('/\s+/','|', $yacht_make);
} else {
    $yacht_make = NULL;
}
```

And I revised the first few lines of the php query building code I posted above to read,

```
if(!empty($yacht_id)) {
    $where = " WHERE yacht_id = $yacht_id ";
} else {

    $where = " WHERE ( yacht_id LIKE '%' )";

    if(!empty($yacht_make)){
        $where .= "AND ( CONCAT_WS(' ',make,model) RLIKE '$yacht_make') ";
    }
```

It is working nicely, although it brings up more results than I would like for "Jeanneau Sun Odyssey" as it brings up "Bayliner Sunbridge", I assume because it is matching "Sun".

But it is a big improvement from what I had.

Thanks All

Rob Fenwick

Answer (score -1):

After checking out your site it appears you are only taking input from one text field and searching for that string in each field.

So, you can either use full text searches ([linkie](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)) or you could split your string by spaces and generate a WHERE cause on the fly.  Here is a rough example:

```
$searchterms = explode (' ', $input);

$sql .= "... WHERE"; /* obviously need the rest of your query */


foreach ($searchterms as $term) {
  if ((substr ($string, -5) != 'WHERE') && 
      (substr ($string, -3) == ' ||') { $sql .= " ||"; }
  $sql .= " make LIKE '%$term%' || model LIKE '%$term%'";
}
```